# How can I add, remove, or swap jQuery validation rules from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

**Note:**
This question refers to a very old version of [jQuery.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (version 1.5). This plugin now provides a built-in solution for doing this: the [`.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) that should be used instead. I'm leaving this question and answer in its original form for historical purposes for anyone who needs to maintain a legacy site that is unable to upgrade to the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery.validate().

---

I have a form that toggles what input elements are visible. I want to validate **only** the visible elements on the form.

I'm having a hard time getting this to function correctly. I want to disable validators for non-visible elements and I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. Any insight to what may be wrong with my code, or my approach would be appreciated.

When visibility is toggled, I've tried a few things:

- Calling `$("form").rules("remove")` to clear all existing validation rules. This throws an "undefined" JavaScript exception.
- Calling `$("form").validation(...options...)` for the visible elements, hoping this would overwrite the rules. This only allows the first group that is validated to work. The second panel can not be validated.
- Unbinding the submit handler before calling the new `validation()` method. This didn't do what I would have thought. It removes all validation (seemingly) permanently and the form submits without validation.
- Clearing out the validation object with `$.removeData($('form'), 'validator')` before trying to call the validator again. This also doesn't work.
- This is in an ASP.NET site, so using multiple `<form />` tags is out of the question since that would break the page.

I'm sort of stumped on how I can make this work. You can see a complete working demo of what I have at [`http://jsbin.com/ucibe3`](http://jsbin.com/ucibe3), or edit it at [`http://jsbin.com/ucibe3/edit`](http://jsbin.com/ucibe3/edit). I've tried to strip it down to *just* the code that causes the bug.

Here are the key pieces of my code (use above links for complete working page)

HTML:

```
<td id="leftform">
    Left Form<br />
    Input 1: <input type="text" name="leftform_input1" /><br />
    Input 2: <input type="text" name="leftform_input2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="leftform_submit" value="Submit Left" />
</td>
<td id="rightform" style="visibility:hidden">
    Right Form<br />
    Input 1: <input type="text" name="rightform_input1" /><br />
    Input 2: <input type="text" name="rightform_input2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="rightform_submit" value="Submit Right" />
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#toggleSwitch').click(function() {
    if ($('#leftform').css("visibility") !== "hidden") {
        $('#leftform').css("visibility", "hidden");
        $('#rightform').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                rightform_input1: { required: true },
                rightform_input2: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                rightform_input1: "Field is required",
                rightform_input2: "Field is required"
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#rightform').css("visibility", "hidden");
        $('#leftform').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                leftform_input1: { required: true },
                leftform_input2: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                leftform_input1: "Field is required",
                leftform_input2: "Field is required"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the mark with the other answer, I've added a link to a possible solution in my post- Hope it helps.

Comment: 2014 - several validator plugins now exist and, although I can make an educated guess, it's not clear which plugin this question refers to. A link up font would be useful.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Good point. I've updated the question and answer to specify the plugin, as well as the version it applies to as this question & answer refer to an obsolete version of the plugin and isn't as relevant any longer.

Comment: Thanks Dan. StackOverflow is a victim of its own success in this regard. As time goes on more and more Qs/As will become obsolete.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Obsolete notice:**
This answer refers to an extremely old version of the [jQuery.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin (version 1.5) and is now obsolete as the plugin provides an official API for solving this problem. See the [`.rules()` documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) for the current approach to solving this. I'm leaving  this answer as-is to help anyone who must maintain a legacy site that is unable to upgrade to the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery.validate().

---

This uses a feature of the validator that is not well documented in the API (and by this I mean it isn't documented at all), however since it is a fundamental part of how the validator works, it is not likely to be removed even if it is undocumented.

Once you've initialized the jQuery validator, you can get access to the validator object again by calling the `validate()` method on the form object you applied the validator to. This validator object has a `settings` property, which stores the default settings, combined with the settings you applied to it in initialization.

Assuming I initialize the validator like this:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        leftform_input1: { required: true },
        leftform_input2: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        leftform_input1: "Field is required",
        leftform_input2: "Field is required"
    }
});
```

I can then get those exact settings out of the validator by doing the following:

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
```

I can then easily work with this settings object to add or remove validators for the form.

This is how you would remove validation rules:

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
delete settings.rules.rightform_input1;
delete settings.messages.rightform_input1;
```

And this is how you would add validation rules:

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
settings.rules.leftform_input1 = {required: true};
settings.messages.leftform_input1 = "Field is required";
```

---

Here is a working solution for the scenario in my question. I use jQuery's `extend()` method to overwrite the `rules` and `messages` properties of the `validate` object, which is how I toggle between the two panels.

```
$('#toggleSwitch').click(function() {
    var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
    var leftForm = $('#leftform');
    var rightForm = $('#rightform');

    if (leftForm.css("visibility") !== "hidden") {
        leftForm.css("visibility", "hidden");
        rightForm.css("visibility", "visible");
        $.extend(settings, {
            rules: {
                rightform_input1: { required: true },
                rightform_input2: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                rightform_input1: "Field is required",
                rightform_input2: "Field is required"
            }
        });
    } else {
        rightForm.css("visibility", "hidden");
        leftForm.css("visibility", "visible");
        $.extend(settings, {
            rules: {
                leftform_input1: { required: true },
                leftform_input2: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                leftform_input1: "Field is required",
                leftform_input2: "Field is required"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I just spent a few hours trying to do something similar, glad you posted your solution.  I found the rule() method supports add/remove rules but I could not find any info on adding rules and messages together.  Your solution in using the settings object worked great! Thanks!

Comment: Any advantage of calling the `validate()` method as opposed to just accessing `$("form").data("validator").settings`?

Comment: @MartinSmith If no validator has been created for the form yet, the call to `data(...)` will return `null`. Calling `validate()` more than once has no side-effects, but if the validator has not been created yet it will create one for you.

Comment: With v1.13.0 of the plugin, I find I can directly set the rules and messages without $.extend(). I just store the rules and messages as objects MyRules, MyMessages and call settings.rules = MyRules; and settings.messages = MyMessages;

Comment: var validation = $('form').validate(); Then call validation.resetForm(); to clear existing errors before changing rule sets. Setting the rules becomes validation.settings.rules = MyRules;

Comment: Brilliant ! I was looking for this for like 2 hours now.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to call validate again with new settings (rules,messages ... etc.)
call

```
$('#formid').removeData('validator')
```

This will remove validation for the form then initialize it again with the new settings

Comment: Was looking all over for this!

Comment: Does this remove all validations on the form?  How you remove just the ones added like "rightform_input1"?

Comment: removes all rules, about removing just a single one check what data is attached to the form, i haven't used jQuery in ages :)

Answer (score 14):

The "required" declarations inside of the validate.rules hash do not have to be statically declared as "true". You can actually supply an anonymous function instead which can check for the visibility of something and return true or false depending on the answer.

```
$('form').validate({
rules: {
  rightform_input1: { 
    required: function(){
              return $('#leftform').css("visibility") !== "hidden"
              } },
  rightform_input2: {
    required: function(){
              return $('#leftform').css("visibility") !== "hidden"
              } }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote, it was a mistake and it won't let me undo it. :(

Comment: You need to return a value from the required function.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#form_id').validate();//empty rules
//add rules/message to form element
$('#form_id #inputId').rules("add", {
    required        : true,                             
    messages        : {
        required    : 'Add your required message'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote small function for editting rules (only required).

```
        $.editRules = function($array, $type) {
            var settings = $('#signupForm').validate().settings;
            $.each($array, function($k, $v) {
                settings.rules[$v] = {required: ($type == 'add' ? true : false)};
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

While there are other ways to do this ASP.net does allow you to use multiple form tags so long as they are not all rendered - so if you use a multi view to only display the relevant content you can use multiple forms.

It tends to clean up validation and submit handling quite a bit.

---

Alternatively jquery does allow :visible to be added to your selector, so you could potentially only run the selector on visible elements and sidestep the issue that way depending on how they are hidden.

> How :visible is calculated was changed in jQuery 1.3.2. Element assumed as visible if it and its parents consumes space in document. CSS visibility isn't taken into account. The release notes outline the changes in more detail.

---

Here is a better / simpler solution from another post on stack overflow-

Apparently the validation plug-in allows you to specify :visible in your rules. Here is the post-

[Advanced JQuery Validation: Avoiding Validations on Certain Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316602/advanced-jquery-validation-avoiding-validations-on-certain-conditions/1316818#1316818)

Comment: I would consider using multiple form tags as you mentioned, however other than validation, the page is complete and there's a lot going on in the page so it would take a lot of restructuring of the page to make this solution work.