# Turn Off MVC3 Attribute Validation Conditionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to create attribute validation for a check box or radio buttons but have that validation not be enforced when it is not applicable. Unfortunately, disabling the control or making it read-only does not turn off the validation.

Does anyone know how from jQuery or JavaScript, I could stop the validation when some state was true (the control was disabled or some other checkbox was unchecked, for example)?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: imho the proper solution is to use two different view models.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this post will help.

[How can I add, remove, or swap jQuery validation rules from a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510165/how-can-i-add-remove-or-swap-jquery-validation-rules-from-a-page)

To sum it up here's the code

```
var settings = $('form').validate().settings;
delete settings.rules.rightform_input1;
delete settings.messages.rightform_input1;
```

Setting would look something like this.

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        leftform_input1: { required: true },
        leftform_input2: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        leftform_input1: "Field is required",
        leftform_input2: "Field is required"
    }
});
```