# Two different validation to a form

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have a form that contain a submit button. I'm using form.validation plugin

I have already set the rules. It's ok!

But now I created a link out of form that when the user clicks, i would like to change these rules. Is it possible?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $(".myform").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true
            },
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form class="myform">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<a href="#">Call me</a>
```

When the user clicks on "Call me", the validation would be only the "phone" field.

Comment: Don't know what `form.validation` plugin is.

Comment: can you at least post some code or describe what youve actually tried?

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current state, can you please post more information or remove the question before it gets bombed. IE What rules? code samples. Form code. Plugin code. Anything

Comment: Now with more details...

Comment: None of the rules will apply in what you have posted as the link is outside the scope of the jquery call. I think you probably want to link call me through to another form with new rules on

Comment: in fact the form wont even submit in its current state :-(

Comment: It's exactly like a wrote. The link is outside. It's a simple link that requires the 'phone' field. So i need to define a new validation when the user click in this link instead of submit a form.

Comment: Now is working. Is it possible to set new rules when the user click in "Call me" link? Only in this case I would like to require the "phone" field.

Comment: do you understand the code you have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lots wrong with this code both syntactically and structure

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$(".myform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        },
    }
});
});
</script>
<form class="myform">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
</form>
<a href="#">Call me</a>
```

should look more like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#callme").click(function(){
   $(".myform").validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true
        }
    /*note the removed ,*/
    }
});
});
$("#submit").click(function(){
$(".myform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        }
    /*note the removed ,*/
    }
});
});
});
</script>
<!-- Your Form must have a method attribute either post or get //-->
<form class="myform" method="post" action="">
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<label for="phone">Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
<!-- Hide this label with css //-->
<label for="submit" class="hidden">submit:</label><input type="submit" value="submit" text="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<!-- Link this to another form with new js validation rules //-->
<a href="#" id="callme">Call me</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I know all the errors that you showed me, my form has a lot of field, I only adapted to ask here in stackoverflow. So I thinked that are unnecessary provide all of these details. But I already edited. Tha form must be the same, this is my question, is it possible?

Comment: it is but you need to understand what you have written

Comment: you would need to do some sort of event listened on the elements. One on the link and one on the button

Comment: this works http://jsfiddle.net/g3Byh/2/ id appreciate it if you accepted my answer

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas King ;) I'm new in stack overflow, so i'm still learning how to use it... but there's a problem, it only work at second click... I don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by only works at second click? if you can elaborate i may be able to help :-)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/osnysantos/g3Byh - The first time that you click in "call me", it doesn't work, only works at second time that you click. Pay attention, don't click in submit, only in "Call me". @nicholas King

Comment: i think this is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510165/how-can-i-add-remove-or-swap-jquery-validation-rules-from-a-page

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you need to do the following when your link is clicked (all in javascript / jQuery):

- cancel the default action for the link;
- remove the rules from `name` and `email`;
- add a new rule to the `phone` field;
- optionally hide all fields but the `phone` field.

You can find more details in the [rules section](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules) of the documentation of the plugin.

Comment: much simpler to stick event listen on the link and button and amend set the validation rules in the event. Otherwise the rules get lost in the code

Comment: @Nicholas King That will not work in this case as (according to the manual) the `validate` method `sets up event handlers for submit, focus, keyup, blur and click to trigger validation of the entire form or individual elements`. So if you bind it after the event has already been fired, that will be too late.

Comment: just read the docs but im pretty sure my methods below should work with a little playing about and using the valid method instead of validate. Otherwise its a case of using the plugins rules() method like you have suggested

Comment: although if he is just checking for empty fields i think it would be much easier just using a jquery check sans the plugin

Comment: odds either of us get upvotes or an accepted answer from Osny Santos Netto? slim to none! :-)

Comment: I need a form with so customized.. i need to use this plugin. The answer is: you're right, this is the proccess taht I need.

Answer (score 1):

This way worked. In my tests I see that:

- Cannot be a link
- Cannou be out of

Can someone confirm?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit1").click(function(){
   $(".myform").validate({
    rules: {
        phone: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
});
$("#submit").click(function(){
$(".myform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
});
});
</script>
<!-- Your Form must have a method attribute either post or get //-->
<form class="myform" method="post" action="">
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<label for="phone">Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
<!-- Hide this label with css //-->
<input type="submit" value="submit" text="submit" id="submit" />
<input type="submit" value="submit1" text="submit" id="submit1" />
</form>
<!-- Link this to another form with new js validation rules //-->
```

Comment: This code works identically to mine below. An anchor is perfectly capable of submitting a form.

Comment: This code was based in your, but your wasn't working... I only din't understand why.

Comment: i think this is a possible solution using the settings array although this seems to be a common problem!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510165/how-can-i-add-remove-or-swap-jquery-validation-rules-from-a-page