# jQuery validation - Change min max number checking at runtime

Tags: jquery, validation

Can I change the min, max of a number's validation at runtime ?

I use [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

My simplified layout and structure to demonstrate how it should work. when I change the value of max range the max range's validation of the field number has to be changed too.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nXqd/qC2Ya/3/

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your current implementation, the relevant script and html? Maybe even a fiddle on jsfiddle.net is possible?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl added the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/qC2Ya/5/

---

You can do this by specifying `min` and `max` options in your validation rules:

For ex:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      min: 13
    }
  }
});
```

**API Docs**:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/max#value

Comment: The OP is looking to change this at runtime, e.g. when some event happens

Comment: sorry for being too quick, I post my jsfiddle so you can take a look at it more easier,

Answer (score 6):

Using this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510165/how-can-i-add-remove-or-swap-jquery-validation-rules-from-a-page) from another SO post as a guide I was able to change your code and get this to work.

```
// Bind initial rule;
bindRangeRule(1, 2);

$("input[name='change-range']").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    // add some validation here off course to ensure only numbers are accepted.
    // You can do that by checking the event.keyCode values I believe.
    // If an invalid value was specified you can throw an alert
    // or simply clear the input field and return false. Or similar.

    // re-bind range rule
    bindRangeRule(1, parseInt(value));
});

function bindRangeRule(from, to) {
    var settings = $('form').validate().settings;

    delete settings.rules.number;

    settings.rules.number = {
        required: true,
        range: [from, to]
    }
};
```

Comment: You are awesome..Thanks

Comment: demo returns 404